# nexmo user:create is not working in Nexmo-cil

Tags: vonage

nexmo user:create command is not working in Nexmo-cli.  I tried to run below code, but it is not recognized as a command.

nexmo user:create name="david".

However, many nexmo documents and tutorials mention about this command. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you please confirm that you have installed the beta version of the CLI via npm `install nexmo-cli@beta -g`

You can find the relevant documentation at https://github.com/nexmo/nexmo-cli/tree/beta.

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Javier

Comment: Thanks Javier. When I installed beta version of nexmo-cli, it worked.